# Rendering dynamic text on camera image

Tags: android

I want to display the 4 text views on 4 corners of the camera. This text is to be retrieved from a database i.e the the input for the text view is to be given dynamically.
Can any one please help me with how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a linear layout and add textview to it to it... The same can be added to a camera view(SurfaceView). Start following calss from your Activity and call DisplayText() function, wheever you want to update the text in the camera view.

```
public class CameraApps extends SurfaceView implements Camera.PreviewCallback
{
    private     Context DisCtx                  = null;
    private     Camera camera                   = null;

    public OTPCamera(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
        this.DisCtx             = ctx;
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    public void DisplayText(String text1,String text2,String text3,String text4)
     {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutpar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        TextView txtview = new TextView(DisCtx);
        txtview.setText(text1);
        txtview.setTextSize(25);
        txtview.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        txtview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        ((Activity)DisCtx).addContentView(txtview, layoutpar);



         TextView txtview1 = new TextView(DisCtx);
         txtview1.setText(text2);
         txtview1.setTextSize(25);
         txtview1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
         txtview1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         ((Activity)DisCtx).addContentView(txtview1, layoutpar);

         TextView txtview2 = new TextView(DisCtx);
         txtview2.setText(text3);
         txtview2.setTextSize(25);
         txtview2.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT);
         txtview2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         ((Activity)DisCtx).addContentView(txtview2, layoutpar);

         TextView txtview3 = new TextView(DisCtx);
         txtview3.setText(text4);
         txtview3.setTextSize(25);
         txtview3.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
         txtview3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         ((Activity)DisCtx).addContentView(txtview3, layoutpar);



    }
```

}